# Flask + Wsgi returning python shell script output

Tags: python, flask

I have deployed two containers flask + wsgi and nginx I have a simple code which works returning hello world.

When I try to return the output of a python shell script to a webpage I get internal server error, the script it works via cli it even prints the output of docker ps.

Working code returns a simple hello world :

```
# app.py
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello world!'
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

Not working code i get internal server error please help im not really sure why ... or how to debug it

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess

def dockers():
    call = subprocess.call('docker ps', shell=True)
    return call

#!/user/bin/env python
from flask import Flask
from cont import dockers
app = Flask(__name__)
print(dockers())
@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return dockers()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont ever try to pass an object to a web page youll have a bad time. i wrote the result into a file split the lines to a list and returned it to the webpage.

Comment: :D yep it was hard to get to that because it worked in cli lesson wont be forgotten